# How to split words in ASP.NET MVC4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How to split words in ASP.NET MVC4?

This is what I am try so far.

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var aaa = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split("12:::34:::55", ":::");

            ViewBag.test = aaa;
            return View();
        }
```

but the page shows `System.String[]`.

Comment: Your code works correctly and returns a string array, What do you want to do with it?

Comment: Please post code of the correspondent `view`

Comment: `string.Split` is enough - no need for regex here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing the `string` representation of an array.

To show the elements, use [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/57a79xd0.aspx):

```
ViewBag.test = string.Join(",", //insert separator here
                           aaa);
```

This will return `"12,34,55"`.

If you want to have separate lines, replace the `","` with `Environment.NewLine`. You can also have spaces with `" "`, or any other separator of your choice.

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over `ViewBag.test` in your view.

Comment: usually, I make my views as simple as possible and try to eliminate loops and conditions there

Comment: Then what is the question? `string.Split` is the way (in this case) to split the words.

Comment: You shouldn't care about for loops. If you want to generate html or line breaks and assign that to Viewbag.test, it's a lot worse.

Answer (score 1):

This would split your string and return an array like so:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    string[] elements = string.Split("12:::34:::55", ":::");

    ViewBag.test = elements;
    return View();
}
```

**EDIT**

Here is how you iterate through the elements in your view:

```
@foreach (string element in ViewBag.test)
{
    <span>@element</span>
    // or other things ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your view you should loop over the value:

```
@foreach (string item in ViewBag.test)
{
    <p>@item</p>
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you have just used `Split("x:::y:::z",":::")` in this case it returns array of string so its showing you the message `System.String[]`

if you want it in an array of string mention it as

```
string s = "x:::y:::z";
string[] Splittedwords=s.Split(new string[] { ":::" }, System.StringSplitOptions.None);
```

otherwise if you want only the first one from it you can use

```
var x = s.Split(new string[] { ":::" }, System.StringSplitOptions.None)[0];
```

here `[0]` represents the first split gives you x, `[1]` gives you y.

Now you can give `ViewBag.test = Splittedwords;` to pass to the view.
otherwise `ViewBag.test = x;` to pass single character.

Note: remember in View you have to perform typecasting otherwise you will continue to get the same error